# .htaccess redirect without change url same host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, cpanel

I want to redirect a subdomain inside panel, the subdomain `editor.domain.com`

It should redirect to `domain.com/cmseditor`.

However the visitor should see `editor.domain.com`.

So far I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^editor\.homecatering\.pt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://homecatering.pt/cmseditor%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Same hosting setup? Can you explain better?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

 # If the subdomain is "editor.homecatering.pt"
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^editor.homecatering.pt$ [NC]
 # Then rewrite any request to directory /cmseditor
 RewriteRule ^((?!cmseditor).*)$ /cmseditor/$1 [NC,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.homecatering\.pt$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://homecatering\.pt/cmseditor/%1
```